# "The data misses a desired object" vs. "a desired object is being missed in the data"

Tags: meaning, passive-voice, active-voice

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning?

> - If the *data misses* a desired object, then information relevant to that object do not exist in the database.
> - If a desired object *is being missed in the data*, then information relevant to that object do not exist in the database.

Comment: The second one isn't grammatical.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: sorry did some ammenments,, do both give same meaning now?

Comment: It is the collecting of data rather than the data itself that would / could miss something. The data would include or fail to include that item.

Comment: The first one isn't grammatical either. *Information* is singular, so it ***does** not exist*, not ***do** not exist*. The whole idea of *data **missing** objects* is so metaphorically weird anyway that I think the sentence is only marginally "English" in the first place.

Comment: @niro - see Barrie's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They give the same meaning, but not the same emphasis. The active form foregrounds the data, while the passive form foregrounds the desired object.